# Variable is not getting its value

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending email through PHP mailer for account verification, and it's sending and working. But there is an error in `$mail->body` part, because I'm passing `$name` variable to the `<a>` tag, but when I click on my received mail, it's still `$name`. It should be the posted name of my form but it's just displaying the `$name` text and not getting the value of `$name`. I think the problem is in this line (a syntax problem).

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Body = '<b>Hello,this is just account activation process please click</b><a href="http://localhost/email_verification/register.php?nm=$name">Here</a><b> and you will be good to go.</b>';
?>
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded when you use single quotes.

Comment: what is your form method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use double quote in your Body method.

```
$mail->Body    = "<b>Hello,this is just account activation process please click</b><a href=\"http://localhost/email_verification/register.php?nm=".$name."\">Here</a><b> and you will be good to go.</b>";
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain why does this fixes his problem, so OP can learn from that.

Comment: Yeah it works thankyou...

Comment: and why is there concatenation aruond .$name.

Comment: Because You could join two or more  string with dot. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @mastermind - Concatenation is not necessary in this case, you can write `"hello $name"` and `$name` will be replaced by the contents of the variable. Just remember to use double quotes if you want the variables to be expanded like this. If you want to use single quotes, then you'll have to concatenate. Take a look at PHP docs on [`strings`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio Correct. It's an old habit.

Comment: hmm..i get it..thanks man..